# organising my C++ files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am having a problem organising my c++ files in a single Visual C++ project. I am using Visual Studio.  I am trying to separate my code into several files. If I write everything in one cpp file it works fine. However, when I try to write my functions `exercise1` and `exercise2` in separate cpp files and `trackbarHandler` and `initVideoStream` function in separate cpp files, it fails to build the solution.

Attaching my whole code in a single cpp file: [Code](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj-XjsCU2eXvgckmoa_XVVBK5kuAzw)

What should I do or how should I arrange it?

Comment: First step would be to give us some example code so we are able to detect your problem.

Comment: I think the correct thing you can do is to create a solution, where you put in all your projects. Each project contains then for example a single .cpp, this way you can compile a single project in your solution and run it, without interfiering.

Comment: Did you put declarations for the common bits into a header that is included into each of the .cpp files? see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include and http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/

Comment: Can you please add to your question the reason why your project fails to build when you distribute your functions across multiple files?

Comment: Please also provide a minimal example that reproduces your issue (write some code with just 2 functions, separate them into files like you're trying to do that with your code, describe how exactly you do that and what exact issue do you get).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

main file:

**opencv_test.cpp**

create cpp files and headers for your exercises

**exercise1.h**

---

```
#pragma once
void exercise1();
```

**exercise1.cpp**

copy in your function

```
#include "stdafx.h" // and any additional headers
void exercise1() 
{ 
  ... 
}
```

now do the same for your exercise2

in your opencv_test.cpp include the headers

---

```
#include "exercise1.h"
#include "exercise2.h"

int main()
{
  exercise1();
  exercise2();
}
```

In your project include the files opencv_test.cpp, exercise1.h/.cpp, exercise2.h/.cpp

They can be all in the same folder on your disk, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks dude it worked...